# Add, Delete values from a multiple select box using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a multiple selectbox with cities to a corresponded country which enable users to select multiple cities. In the form filling process, user has to select the country first, and the cities need to changed in the multiple selectbox accordingly. Here below my country select box and cities multiple SB.

```
<select name="country" id="country" onchange="ajax_change(this.value)">
    <option value="">--Select Country--</option>
    <? echo $countryList;?>
</select>
```

and here is the multiple selectbox

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="cities[]" id="cities[]" style="height:150px; width:300px;">
    <option value="">-- Select City --</option> 
</select>
```

This is the ajax code which is returning successfully the cities list.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ajax_change(val)
    {

        jQuery.post(
            '<?=WEB_ROOT?>index.php?rt=admin/airport/ajax',
            {
                val:val,
                type:'get_cities'
            },
            function(data){
                $('#cities[]').val(data);
            }
        );
    }
</script>
```

But `$('#cities[]').val(data)` is not working. Can you please anyone help me on this.

Comment: Give this a try: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z4v6V/) You want to use the [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) function to loop over the return data (I am assuming it is JSON) and then append newly created <option/> items to your <select/> list. **EDIT** I just tried the jsfiddle and added the square brackets like you have in your select list name and it broke the fiddle. I don't know if that means it would have the same result, but it is likely. Is there any way you can remove those square brackets from the name? That may be the cause of your problem.

Comment: Your id is invalid. It should not contain brackets. Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yBKPa/1/) that updates the text of your current entry and properly loads the JSON data into the select.

Comment: Hi @jesus.tesh your answer is suits me to perfection. Thankyou very verymuch. You should give this as a post, other than a comment. Then I could rate you. Thannxx anyway..

Comment: It was an answer, but a moderator converted and deleted it. Not sure why...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) function to loop over the return data (I am assuming it is JSON) and then append newly created  items to your  list.

Give this a try:

**HTML**

```
<select id='select' />​
```

**Javascript**

```
var data = {
    'name1':'value1',
    'name2':'value2'
};

$.each(data, function(key, value) {
    $('#select').append($("<option/>").text(key).val(value));
});
```

The above in jsfiddle: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z4v6V/)

You also want to remove the square brackets from the ID.

Comment: Please move the relevant contents of the fiddle into the answer.  Otherwise, this is considered a link-only answer and doesn't do much good (and it will be converted into a comment, *again*).

Answer (score 1):

Just use a class and remove the [] from the id tag

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="cities[]" class="cities" style="height:150px; width:300px;">
    <option value="">-- Select City --</option>
</select>
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ajax_change(val)
    {
       //alert(val);

       jQuery.post('<?=WEB_ROOT?>index.php?rt=admin/airport/ajax',
           {val:val,type:'get_cities'},
           function(data){
               $('.cities').val(data);
           }
       );
    }
</script>
```

Comment: @jim Unfortunately this is not working too. I guess .val() may not working with select boxes.

Comment: @Ariks I did not provide this ansewr. I just edited the formatting.

Comment: Aha...Sorry.. I didnt Noticed that..!